# Oracle trigger to keep a copy of deleted records in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using this trigger to keep a copy of the deleted record from table `Orders_Details` in table `Orders_Details_Deleted`.

I am using this trigger for two reasons:

1. security, in case the record is accidentally deleted
2. to keep a history of deleted records by the user

Is there any better way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_Record_Deleted
   BEFORE DELETE
   ON Orders_Details
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Orders_Details_Deleted
      SELECT *
        FROM Orders_Details
       WHERE Orders_Details.Order_ID = Orders_Details.Order_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Do you need to actually delete the row? You could just have a column in the table to indicate it has been deleted/voided.

Comment: @forsvarir its for two reason first one is security in case the record accidentally deleted and to keep history of deleted record by user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using this trigger to keep a copy of the deleted record from table Orders_Details in table Orders_Details_Deleted.

No, you're not. The code copies all rows from `orders_details` to `order_details_deleted` every time the trigger is run.

> Is there any better way [than using a trigger] ?

Yes, there is a better way. Don't reinvent database features but use native functionality instead. Have a look for the following Oracle features:

[Flashback Data Archive](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011)

> A Flashback Data Archive provides the ability to track and store transactional changes to a table over its lifetime. A Flashback Data Archive is useful for compliance with record stage policies and audit reports.

[Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023)

> Auditing is the ability to track changes that users make in the database.

[Workspace Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADWSM/long_intro.htm#ADWSM010)

> Keep a history of changes to data
>
> You can navigate workspaces and row versions to view the database as of a particular milestone or point in time. You can roll back changes to a row or table in a workspace to a milestone. A typical example might be a land information management application where Workspace Manager supports regulatory requirements by maintaining a history of all changes to land parcels.